# jQuery prepend() within a for loop after having picked up an array from a textarea

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop, prepend

Hi and thanks for reading.

I am trying to permit users to paste text into a textarea field and then work with what they pasted.

The application is limited in scope but users will be pasting the contents of a csv file where the first column lines up with div Ids that I have set up.

For some reason, when I alert within this loop it alerts perfectly. The problem is when I try to prepend() the contents instead of alterting them, it just does nothing:

```
        $('#datainput').submit(function () {
        csvData = $("#csvData").val();
        csvData = csvData.split('\n');
        var iterationNum;
        var contentText;

        return function() {
            for (var i=0, lngth=csvData.length; i < lngth; i+=1) {
                csvData[i] = csvData[i].split(',');
                if (!!$('#' + csvData[i][0]).length){
                    iterationNum = '#' + csvData[i][0]
                    contentText = '<div class=\"percentageLabel\">' + csvData[i][1] + '</div>';
                    $(iterationNum).prepend(contentText); 
                }
            }   

        }();
    });
```

This on the other hand works (it works when I alert):

```
    $('#datainput').submit(function () {
        csvData = $("#csvData").val();
        csvData = csvData.split('\n');
        var iterationNum;
        var contentText;

        return function() {
            for (var i=0, lngth=csvData.length; i < lngth; i+=1) {
                csvData[i] = csvData[i].split(',');
                if (!!$('#' + csvData[i][0]).length){
                    iterationNum = '#' + csvData[i][0]
                    contentText = '<div class=\"percentageLabel\">' + csvData[i][1] + '</div>';
                    alert(iterationNum + contentText); 
                }
            }   

        }();
    });
```

I've even tested by replacing the iterationNum variable with an actual id like #MyID for example and it does not work within the loop. Using the each same expression outside of the loop the prepend works:

```
                        contentText = '<div class=\"percentageLabel\"></div>';
                    $(MyID).prepend(contentText);
```

But if I use that code within the loop I get nothing.

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong here?

The first code snippet above is the one I want to work, the others are simply to show what else I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like in:

```
iterationNum = '#' + csvData[i][0]; /* Don't forget your ;'s! */
contentText = '<div class=\"percentageLabel\">' + csvData[i][1] + '</div>';
$(iterationNum).prepend(contentText);
```

`$(iterationNum)` may not be a valid selector. Change it to:

```
iterationNum = '#' + csvData[i][0]; /* Don't forget your ;'s! */
contentText = '<div class=\"percentageLabel\">' + csvData[i][1] + '</div>';
alert(( $(iterationNum)[0] != null  ));
```

And tell me whether it alerts true or false.

Comment: thank you for the reply! It alerts true but the prepend still doesn't do add anything

Comment: Seeing some HTML would really help, but change it to `alert( $(iterationNum).prepend(contentText).html() )` and let me know if it alerts with your prepend-ed HTML.

Comment: that's strange, it alert with the prepend-ed html but when I look at the actual html in the console the prepend-ed html is no longer there

Comment: `code`   <div id="pasteForm" class="popup_block">  
   <form id="datainput">
    <fieldset><legend><span>Paste Data from Comma Separated CSV File</span></legend></fieldset>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <label for="pasteArea">Data Paste Area:</label>
      <textarea name="csvData" id="csvData" cols="50" rows="8"></textarea>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" class="button terminalButton" value="Submit Data" />
   </form>
  </div>
`

Comment: added some of the html above. the other interesting this, may help figure out what's wrong, is that the #fade div disappears too even though I changed the function to hide() it instead of removing it from the dom

Comment: I got it, prevent default! e.preventDefault(); thank you so much. I never would have found the error if you didn't have me alert what was actually happening

Comment: Sure...I just feel angry with myself for forgetting that the form was submitting.

Comment: Oh no problem at all. If I'd have sent you the html you would have seen it. Your questions helped point me in the right direction